# How to add a specific text after a specific line from html form to txt file(actually html)

Tags: php

I have a php code that adds me some text after specific line in html file.
It actually works perfectly, but the problem is that it adds me a really specific text as set in variables:

```
$variable1 = "text";
```

What i want to do, is this: This php file, to take me data from one html form that i already have, and write me in other html file with specific html tags, BUT to write it just after a specific line.

How i want to look my new text from html form to html file:

```
<tr>
    <td class="column1"> a timestamp </td>
    <td class="column2"> first variable from form named as **name**</td>
    <td class="column2"> second variable from form named as **city**</td>
    <td class="column2"> third variable from form named as **phone**</td>
    <td class="column2"> 4th variable from form named as **email**</td>
</tr>
```

I want php to write in list.html just after the `<tbody>` line. ( i mean under this line ).
I already connected HTML Form with this php file through `action` attribute.
Here are my codes:

HTML CODE WHERE I WANT PHP TO WRITE A NEW TEXT:

```
<tbody> //I want my new like just after this.
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">2017-09-29 01:22</td>
        <td class="column2">alex</td>
        <td class="column3">my city</td>
        <td class="column4">07xxxx45</td>
        <td class="column4">myemail@email.com</td>
    </tr>
```

A php code that works perfectly but not as i described in this post:

```
$config = 'test.html';
$file=fopen($config,"r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$date = date("F j, Y");
$time = date("H:i:s");

$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$email = "email";
$newuser = $username . " " . $password . " " . $email . " " . $date . " " .    $time."\r\n";   // I added new line after new user
$insertPos=0;  // variable for saving //Users position
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line=fgets($file);
    if (strpos($line, 'jg')!==false) {
        $insertPos=ftell($file);    // ftell will tell the position where the pointer moved, here is the new line after //Users.
        $newline =  $newuser;
    } else {
        $newline.=$line;   // append existing data with new data of user
    }
}

fseek($file,$insertPos);   // move pointer to the file position where we saved above
fwrite($file, $newline);

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, It is not properly managed content, that you want to apply some text after `<tbody>`, can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: I don't know how more specific to be.

I want just to add some a text like this:
```
<td class="column1">
```
from php to html, how can i do it ?

Comment: `to take me data from one html form that i already have` can you please post this html form? 

Typically you would set your form to method post and then once the form is submitted, check if the post globals are set, then assign those values to variables that can be displayed anywhere in your php page.

Comment: did you please read my first post? everything is working good. My html form sends data to my database, and write it as it is in my other html if i want. but i don't want so, i want it to be wrote between html tags as shown in my first post. thank you

Answer (score 1):

First we create the form that will send the post, once the post is sent we check to make sure the buttons name is in the post global array and if that is set we set variables to the post data. Do cleaning of user input, *I am not getting into sanitation in this answer, but always clean user data appropriately* then get the timestamp and display those values in your table.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
        Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
//echo the results of $stmt that holds our data
<?=$stmt?>
```

PHP:

```
$stmt = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//check if the form button is set in POST 
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $city = strip_tags($_POST['city']);
    $number = strip_tags($_POST['number']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");;
    $timeStamp = date("m-d-Y h:i:sa");
    $stmt .= '
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">'.$timeStamp.'</td>
        <td class="column2">'.$name.'</td>
        <td class="column3">'.$city.'</td>
        <td class="column4">'.$number.'</td>
        <td class="column4">'.$email.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables:

```
$date = date("F j, Y");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$username = "user";
$city = "Sidney";
$telephone = "009909090";
$password = "pass";
$email = "email";
```

How to mix with html:

```
$line = "<tbody> 
<tr>
<td class='column1'>$data $time</td>
<td class="column2">$username</td>
<td class="column3">$city</td>
<td class="column4">$telehone</td>
<td class="column4">$email</td>
</tr>
</tbody>";
fputs($file,$line);
```